# Derivative Of $\ln(x)$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

It is required to find the derivative of the natural logarithm of $x$: $\frac {d}{dx}\ln(x)$
My solution:
Let $f(x)=\ln(x) $ then $f'(x)=\frac {d}{dx}\ln(x)    $
By definition:$$f'(x)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{h} $$
By substitution:$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+h)- \ln(x)}{h} $$
Since $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(\frac ab)$, then:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(\frac{x+h}x)}{h}$$
Since $a\times \ln(b) = \ln(a^b)$, then:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\ln((\frac{x+h}x)^\frac 1h)$$
Then:$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\ln((1+\frac hx)^\frac 1h)$$
How to continue?
Are there any other ways to find the derivative?
Thanks in advance!
Note: It is not allowed to use the fact that: $(e^x)'=e^x$
     $$ e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$? If so, that is probably the best route to take.

Comment: Sorry, but no :$

Comment: Using the continuity of $\ln$ you can take the limit inside the logarithm.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 Then ??? Is it the same as what the answers posted imply???

Comment: yes, but none of them emphasize this important point.

Comment: Can you use $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{ds}{s}$ ??  If not, what is your definition of $\ln$??

Comment: @GEdgar: No, the definition of $ln$ relies on the definition of $log$. $log_c(a)=b$ then $a = c^b$. $ln$ is when $c = e$ Euler's Number. Then if $ln(a)=b$ then $a=e^b$.

Comment: And you do know about $c^b$ where $b$ is irrational?

Comment: @YousefKaddoura Often the formula in GEdgar's comment is taken to be the definition of $\ln$ (which has various advantages) in which case the property you cite is a consequence, rather than the other way around. Using your definition, which essentially declares it to be the inverse of $x \mapsto e^x$, computing the derivative is tantamount to computing $\frac{d}{dx} e^x$ (and so presumably why you cannot use $(e^x)' = e^x$).

Comment: @GEdgar: Unfortunetly, No :$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Recall the definition of $e$:

$e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$

Or equivalently:

$e=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \left(1+h\right)^{1/h}$

You can use that

$e^u=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \left(1+hu\right)^{1/h}$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You're nearly there with your approach. One method is to use substitution and let $\frac{h}{x} = u$, then consider the limit as $u \rightarrow 0$.

Note that $\lim \limits_{u \rightarrow 0}(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}} = e$ (*[Why?](http://math2.org/math/constants/e.htm)*)

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this via the chain rule:
\begin{align}
y & = \log x \qquad \text{(or ``$\ln x$'' if you like)} \\[10pt]
x & = e^y \\[10pt]
\frac{dx}{dy} & = e^y \\[10pt]
\frac{dx}{dy} & = x \\[10pt]
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac 1 x.
\end{align}
Where do you see the chain rule above?  I wasn't explicit about that.  Here's a more explicit version:
\begin{align}
x & = \exp(\log x). \\[10pt]
1 = \frac{dx}{dx} & = \underbrace{\frac d {dx} \exp\log x = (\exp'\log x) \cdot\log' x}_{\text{chain rule}} = (\exp\log x) \cdot \log' x = x\log'x. \\[10pt]
1 & = x \log' x. \\[10pt]
\frac 1 x & = \log' x.
\end{align}

Comment: Here you used that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ which is not what OP wanted, although this is what I would do normally as well.

Comment: I see where my mistake is... I should have provided the definition of e.